# Jersey omits XmlTransient annotation during serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

There was a requirment formating `java.util.Date` into string rather than timestamp in json.

```
{
    "partyName": "Lifecare Pharmaceuticals",
    "partyShortName": null,
    "lastUpdateDate": 1486639814590, // replace with dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss
}
```

To achive the date formatting I added the following ObjectMapperProvider

```
@Provider
@Component
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

   @Override
   public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
      objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
      return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

The above solution worked but creates another issue ignoring XmlTransient annotation. In model classes `Party` has collection of `PartyContacts` and `PartyContact` mapped like

```
@Column(name = "PARTY_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARTY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch =FetchType.LAZY)
private Party party;
```

and getter method

```
@XmlTransient
public Party getParty() {
    return party;
}
```

Here the XmlTransient annotation didnt work hence json loading recursively. I've seen  onemore @JsonIgnore annotation but cant make it work with XmlTransient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jackson 2.x it can be achieved with a proper [`AnnotationIntrospector`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector.html).

### Supporting both Jackson and JAXB annotations

To support both Jackson and JAXB annotations, you need a  [`JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.html) and a [`JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.html). Both introspectors can be combined with an [`AnnotationIntrospectorPair`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotationIntrospectorPair.html):

```java
AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospectorPair(primary, secondary);
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
```

### Supporting only JAXB annotations

If you want to support only JAXB annotations, register only the [`JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.html):

```java
AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
```

### Dependency

To use the [`JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.html), the following dependency is required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details, have a look at the [`jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` module documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Perfect, works. I've one more question, rather than providing `new ObectMapper` cant we access existing objectMapper which Jersey uses default and attach the extra config?

Comment: @vels4j There's no such thing as _existing `ObjectMapper`_. The serialisation and deserialization are handled by other Jackson APIs.